# Sending Multiple Messages using Sim300 gsm/gprs module

Tags: embedded, gsm, at-commands, sim

I have interfaced [SIM300](http://www.positronindia.in/datasheet/DS_PT0006.pdf) Gsm module with lpc2468 through UART. My main motive is to send SMS when some special sequence run. Now my requirement is that I should send the same messages to two numbers.

Is it possible to send message to multiple numbers giving `AT+CMGS` command only once?

Right now I do:

```
AT+CMGF=1 //TEXT MODE
AT+CSCS ="GSM" //SET GSM MODE
AT+CMGS="+9198........." //FOR FIRST NUMBER
> HELLO
CTRL+Z

AT+CMGS="+91981........" //FOR SECOND NUMBER
> HELLO
CTRL+Z

Is something like this possible

AT+CMGS="+9198........","+91981........."
>HELLO
CTRL+Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter that contains the number is the GSM 03.40 destination address and only allows a single value. You'll need to loop through the list of recipients and send multiple commands to send multiple messages. If you check [GSM 03.40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40) on Wikipedia you'll see the TP-DA destination address only allows 2-12 octets.